# Why would the BooleanFilter not appear to be available to me?

Tags: lucene.net

I have installed the `Lucene.Net` nuget package into a class library targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2. I've been able to create an index, and also have been able to construct a query with a filter to search the index.

I now need to combine multiple filters, and was hoping to use the `BooleanFilter`.

Unless I'm misunderstanding [the documents](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/dc6/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_boolean_filter.html), Lucene.Net's `BooleanFilter` should be available in the `Lucene.Net.Search` namespace. I can see other classes in this namespace, but I can't see `BooleanFilter`.

[image]

Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and prior, the BooleanFilter is in the [Lucene.Net.Contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/3.0.3) nuget package in the `Lucene.Net.Queries` namespace.

For Lucene.Net 4.8.0 beta, BooleanFilter is available in the [Lucene.Net.Queries](https://www.myget.org/feed/lucene-net/package/nuget/Lucene.Net.Queries) package under the `Lucene.Net.Queries` namespace.

For the complete listing of available continuous integration packages for the next gen of Lucene.Net, see [the gallery page](https://www.myget.org/gallery/lucene-net/).

So, no it doesn't look like you are misunderstanding the documentation - the documentation is wrong.